App Fails to Run on iOS Simulator After Adding firebase_auth: Swift Compiler Errors in Xcode
Whenever I add the firebase_auth package to my Flutter project, my app doesn't run on the simulator. Does anyone have any ideas about this?
Exceptions
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Expected declaration
/Users/maac/StudioPrjects/pet_panda_app/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Swift/Auth/Auth.swift:287:2
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Expected declaration
/Users/maac/StudioPrjects/pet_panda_app/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Swift/AuthProvider/OAuthProvider.swift:42:2
i tried all of these things
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
pod install
platform :ios, '12.0'
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
cd ..

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
